# Can I convert OpenID Stack Overflow login into standard login?

Tags: discussion, openid, login

My Stack Overflow account is using an OpenID to login. Can I convert this to a normal Stack Overflow account? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a "normal stackoverflow account". Stack Exchange does offer [its own OpenIDs](https://openid.stackexchange.com/), and you can add one of those to your account if you want. Go to [your profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427687/wes), and click "my logins" at the top:

[image: Screenshot of the my logins link]

Choose "add more logins…", and at the bottom of that page click the link under "To create a new Stack Exchange account, click here". Once you've added the Stack Exchange OpenID to your account you can optionally remove your other OpenID, through the same "my logins" dialog

Comment: +1 for pointing out that logins and accounts are not the same thing. Logins are analogous to having many entrances to a house, analogous to an account. Front door, back door, crawling through a window, etc. they all lead to the same place.